# Let $H,K \trianglelefteq G$. Show that if $H$ and $K$ are solvable then the subgroup $HK$ is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H,K \trianglelefteq G$. Show that if $H$ and $K$ are solvable then the subgroup $HK$ is solvable.

*I did the following*:
Since H is solvable, there is a subnormal series $\{e\} = H_0 \trianglelefteq H_1 \trianglelefteq ... \trianglelefteq H_n = H$, with $\frac{H_{i+1}}{H_i}$ abelian.
By $H,K \trianglelefteq G$ then $HK \trianglelefteq G$.
Thus, considering the chain $\{e\} = H_0 \trianglelefteq H_1 \trianglelefteq ... \trianglelefteq H_n = H \trianglelefteq HK$. 
It remains to show that $\frac{HK}{H}$ is abelian. But I'm not getting.

I do not know if there is any error in proof.

Comment: You didn’t use that $K$ is solvable so far. Maybe you want to employ that and refine the step $H \trianglelefteq HK$ a bit by using the correspondence theorem on the subnormal series $\{e\} = K_0 \trianglelefteq K_1 \trianglelefteq … \trianglelefteq K_m = K$.

Comment: I thought about it, but I'm not seeing how to use this subnormal series.

Comment: Sorry, I actually didn’t think this through, I was thinking of quotients that aren’t there. So probably $HK_0 \trianglelefteq HK_1 \trianglelefteq … \trianglelefteq HK_m = HK$ is indeed a normal subseries with abelian quotients since $HK_i/HK_{i-1} \cong K_i/(HK_{i-1}∩K_i)$ by the second isomorphism theorem, and $K_{i-1} \trianglelefteq HK_{i-1}∩K_i$, so $K_i/(HK_{i-1}∩K_i) \cong \tfrac{K_i/K_{i-1}}{HK_{i-1}∩K_i/K_{i-1}}$ by the third isomorphism theorem, a factor of an abelian group. But that isn’t the simplest way, Pedros way is much prettier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Claim* Suppose $N\lhd G$ is normal. Then $G$ is solvable iff $G/N$ and $N$ are solvable.

*Proof* For you to give.

Now let $G=HK$. Then $K\lhd HK$, $K$ is solvable, and $\dfrac{HK}K\simeq \dfrac{H}{H\cap K}$ is solvable by $(1)$ (any quotient of a solvable group, and any subgroup of a solvable group is solvable), and so $HK$ is solvable by $(1)$.

Suppose $G$ is solvable, hence we have a chain $$1\lhd G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\cdots G_n\lhd G$$

Then show $$1\lhd H\cap G_0\lhd H\cap G_1\lhd\cdots H\cap G_n\lhd H$$  $$1\lhd \frac{H G_0}H\lhd \frac{H G_1}H\lhd\cdots \frac{H G_n}H\lhd G/H$$

are solvable series for $H\leqslant G$ and $G/H$ respectively.

Comment: One minor correction: $HK/K \simeq H/H \cap K$, not $K/H \cap K$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I proved the Clain. But I could not prove that any quotient of a solvable group, and any subgroup of a solvable group is solvable.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should follow a different strategy: $HK/H \cong K/(H \cap K)$. $K$ is solvable and hence any quotient, also $H$ is solvable. Can you conclude that $HK$ is solvable?